# why are these diagonal elements positive

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a positive definite matrix $X\in\mathcal{S}^n_{++}$, where the latter denotes the space of symmetric positive definite matrices. Let $Y$ be just symmetric. We can write $Y$ as $Y=Q\Lambda Q^T$, where $Q$ is a orthogonal matrix. Can we say something about the diagonal elements of $(Q^TX^{-1}Q)$. I suspect that it is true that they are positive, i.e. $(Q^TX^{-1}Q)_{ii}>0$. But how can one see this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse of an SPD matrix $X$ is SPD: it's symmetric, because $(X^{-1})^T=(X^T)^{-1}=X^{-1}$, and its eigenvalues are the inverses of the eigenvalues of $X$.

For an orthogonal matrix $Q$, the matrix $Q^TX^{-1}Q$ is also SPD, since it's [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to $X^{-1}$.

Now, for any SPD matrix $A$, $A_{jj}=e_j^TAe_j>0$, where $e_j$ is the vector with all zero entries except the $j$-th, which is $1$.